# WPF Datagrid Button Datatrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, binding, datagrid

Working on a WPF Datagrid.
The datagrid has a bound source with a column "DateInSource."
The value in the column "DateInSource" can either be NULL or a date.

If the value is `null` I want the button RED and the words on the button should be the "Receive Work."

IF the value is not null I want the button GREEN and the words on the button should be the value of `DateInSource`.

I have created a style resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonFormatStyle" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DateInSource}" Value="X:null" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Receive Work" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have created a button:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="BtnDateInSource" Click="ReceiveWork" Content="{Binding DateInSource}"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonFormatStyle}"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It does not appear that my data trigger is working. Suggestions?

[image: Current Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Value="X:null"` is not valid null-check. it is comparison with `"X:null"` string.

change it like `Value="{x:Null}"`

Comment: DataTrigger works!!  However the words don't appear on the button?

Comment: @Kerry, button become gray, but no text "receive work?" try to remove `Content="{Binding DateInSource}"` in button definition: `<Button  x:Name="BtnDateInSource" Click="ReceiveWork" Content="{Binding DateInSource}"` ..>`.

Comment: @Kerry, `Content="{Binding DateInSource}"` is a *local value* of DependencyProperty. Setter of Style cannot override it